# why this.hashCode() and super.hashCode() returns the same value in subclass?

Tags: java

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

    void m1(){       
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());    // Line 1
        System.out.println(super.hashCode());   // Line 2 
        System.out.println(new A().hashCode()); // Line 3    
    } 
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B bobj=new B();
        bobj.m1();
    }
}
```

I am bit confused here as I am getting same hashCode value at Line 1 and Line 2 whereas Line 3 gives different hashCode.

Comment: It sounds like you might be thinking that the hash code value is based on the class it is called on, but it is not; it is based on the object it is called on.

Comment: I know hash code value is based on the object it is called on. this refers to current class object and super refers to immediate parent class object  so both are different. Then why Line 1 and Line 2 returns same value?

Comment: There is no separate "parent object". It is one object of class B (which extends class A), but it is still one object.

Comment: Whenever you create the instance of subclass, an instance of parent class is created implicitly i.e. referred by super reference variable. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: `an instance of parent class is created implicitly`---this statement is false. There is no instance of the superclass.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of your classes overrides `hashCode()`, therefore the exact same method is called both with `this` and `super`.

The third line gives a different hashcode because it is called on a different object, but the method called is again the same as in the first two lines.

Comment: this keyword refers to current class object and super keyword  refers to immediate parent class object  so both are different. Then why Line 1 and Line 2 returns same value?

Comment: What is a "class object"? There is no such thing in Java.

Comment: I am talking about object of immediate parent-class or super class

Comment: super keyword is used to access direct super class members on the current object. It does not refer to any super class object.Is this statement correct?

Comment: thanks Marko ,for making my understanding about super keyword correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling default `hashCode()` method from Object class, since you having overrides it. So, doen't matter, you call from sub class or super class, it internally calls Object's class `hashCode()` method.

Reason for third one to be different, it's a called on new object. **And it has different Virtual memory address, and Object class `hashCode()` methods returns it**.

Comment: this keyword refers to current class object and super keyword refers to immediate parent class object so both are different. Then why Line 1 and Line 2 returns same value?

Comment: @user3283293 : You havint override the `hashCode()` method in abu or auper class, So, It's will be delegated to Object class `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 0):

> `this` refers to current class object and `super` refers to immediate parent class object so both are different.

There is no separate "parent object". It is one object of class B. Because class B extends class A, any instance of B is also a valid instance of A, but it is still only one object.

Example:

```
class A {
    Object getA() { return this; }
}

class B extends A {
    Object getB() { return this; }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj = new B();
        if (obj.getA() == obj.getB()) {
            System.out.println("Same object");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Different objects");
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs: `Same object`, showing that the `this` object as seen by methods of A and as seen by methods of B is the same.

Hence, so is the hashCode the same.

The use of `super` only distinguishes which method implementation is called if a method is overridden. It does not give access to a different object.